# Don't show active record in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

On my restaurant show page, there is a aside block with restaurants in the same region/city. Like this

```
- @restaurants.each do |b|
            %li.usp
              %span.icon
              %h6 
                =link_to b.name, polymorphic_path([@region, @city, b])
```

this code shows all the restaurants, but also the "active" (the restaurant on which the visitor is at that moment) restaurant. How can I show all the records but not the 'active' one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle it with a method in the Restaurant model.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

  def nearby
    self.class.where("region = ? and id <> ?", region, id) }
  end

end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @restaurant.nearby.each do |restaurant| %>
```

Or rather than a regular method you could use a named scope and pass in a restaurant as an argument.